# Is there a MessageBox equivalent in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

Is there a standard message box in WPF, like WinForms' [`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx), or should I use the WinForms message box?

Answer (score 435, accepted):

The WPF equivalent would be the [`System.Windows.MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx). It has a quite similar interface, but uses other enumerations for parameters and return value.

Comment: The WPF version lacks Retry, Ignore and Cancel button combination though. The only available ones are Ok and Cancel.

Answer (score 255):

You can use this:

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this window?",
                                          "Confirmation",
                                          MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                                          MessageBoxImage.Question);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

For more information, visit *[MessageBox in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/messagebox-in-wpf/)*.

Comment: ... and like in the other answers, the namespace here would be "System.Windows" as oppose to "System.Windows.Forms"

Answer (score 18):

The equivalent to WinForms' `MessageBox` in WPF is called [`System.Windows.MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.aspx).

Answer (score 18):

WPF contains the following MessageBox:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Save?", "Confirm", 
    MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{

}
```

Answer (score 9):

The MessageBox in the Extended WPF Toolkit is very nice.  It's at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.MessageBox after referencing the toolkit DLL.  Of course this was released Aug 9 2011 so it would not have been an option for you originally.  It can be found at [Github](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) for everyone out there looking around.

Answer (score 9):

In WPF it seems this code,

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

is replaced with:

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have your own nice looking wpf MessageBox:
Create new Wpf Windows

here is xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="popup.MessageboxNew"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:popup"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" Opacity="1"
        >
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" Margin="10" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="0" >
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DSE" Color="Black" Direction="270" BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.6" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DSE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth" From="0" To="3" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DSE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BlurRadius" From="0" To="20" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <Grid Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Name="Mask" CornerRadius="8" Background="White" />
            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="White">
                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"/>
                </Grid.OpacityMask>
                <StackPanel Name="StackPanel" >
                    <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTextBox}" Name="TitleBar" IsReadOnly="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" Padding="10" FontFamily="Segui" FontSize="14" 
                             Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal"
                             Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <DockPanel Name="ContentHost" Margin="0,10,0,10" >
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Name="Textbar"></TextBlock>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel Name="ButtonHost" LastChildFill="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Button Margin="10" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="70">Yes</Button>
                        <Button Name="noBtn" Margin="10" Click="cancel_Click" Width="70">No</Button>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

for cs of this file :

```
public partial class MessageboxNew : Window
    {
        public MessageboxNew()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //second time show error solved
            if (Application.Current == null) new Application();
                    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }

        private void cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = false;
        }

        private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.MouseDown += delegate { DragMove(); };
        }
    }
```

then create a class to use this :

```
public class Mk_MessageBox
{
    public static bool? Show(string title, string text)
    {
        MessageboxNew msg = new MessageboxNew
        {
            TitleBar = {Text = title},
            Textbar = {Text = text}
        };
        msg.noBtn.Focus();
        return msg.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

now you can create  your message box like this:

```
var result = Mk_MessageBox.Show("Remove Alert", "This is gonna remove directory from host! Are you sure?");
            if (result == true)
            {
                // whatever
            }
```

copy this to App.xaml inside

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />

            <!--two new guys-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.LightBlue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Green.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

--------------[image: IMAGE of Result]-----------------

My Refrence :
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/

[for logic how can i make my own messagebox](https://github.com/denpalrius/Material-Message-Box/tree/master/BespokeFusion)

Answer (score 7):

As the others say, there is a `MessageBox` in the WPF namespace (`System.Windows`).

The problem is that it is the same old messagebox with <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, etc. Windows Vista and Windows 7 have moved on to use Task Dialogs instead.

Unfortunately there is no easy standard interface for task dialogs. I use [an implementation from CodeProject KB](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TaskDialog.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the code here below helps:

```
using Windows.UI.Popups;
namespace something.MyViewModels
{
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public void aRandonMethode()
        {
            MyMessageBox("aRandomMessage");
        }

        public async void MyMessageBox(string mytext)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(mytext);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Windows.UI.Popups`?

Comment: @Nicolas in [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups), not WPF